# SessionFactory thread safe issue

Tags: nhibernate, thread-safety, singleton, ninject, sessionfactory

Sometimes I get this error stack trace at my web app:

```
   [ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.]
   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) +52
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) +10695474
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value) +10
   NHibernate.Util.ThreadSafeDictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value) +93
   NHibernate.Type.TypeFactory.GetType(NullableType defaultUnqualifiedType, Int32 length, GetNullableTypeWithLength ctorDelegate) +88
   NHibernate.Type.TypeFactory.<RegisterDefaultNetTypes>b__c(Int32 l) +82
   NHibernate.Type.TypeFactory.BuiltInType(String typeName, Int32 length) +46
   NHibernate.Mapping.SimpleValue.GetHeuristicType() +168
   NHibernate.Mapping.SimpleValue.get_Type() +49
   NHibernate.Mapping.SimpleValue.IsValid(IMapping mapping) +30
   NHibernate.Mapping.PersistentClass.Validate(IMapping mapping) +87
   NHibernate.Mapping.RootClass.Validate(IMapping mapping) +21
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.ValidateEntities() +183
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.Validate() +13
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory() +36
   Framework.Data.Code.BaseSessionFactoryProvider..ctor() +74
   Framework.Data.Code.SessionFactoryProvider..ctor() +29
   Framework.Data.Code.NestedSessionManager..cctor() +43
```

My SessionFactoryProvider is thread-safe singletone:

```
 public interface ISessionFactoryProvider
 {
        ISessionFactory GetSessionFactory();
 }
 public abstract class BaseSessionFactoryProvider : ISessionFactoryProvider
 {
        protected readonly ISessionFactory factory;
        public ISessionFactory GetSessionFactory()
        {
            return factory;
        }

        protected BaseSessionFactoryProvider()
        {
            factory = GetConfig().BuildSessionFactory();
        }
        public abstract Configuration GetConfig();
 }
 public class SessionFactoryProvider : BaseSessionFactoryProvider
 {
            public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
            {
                get { return Instance.factory; }
            }
            public override Configuration GetConfig()
            {
                return new Configuration().Configure();
            }
            public static SessionFactoryProvider Instance
            {
                get
                {
                    return NestedSessionManager.sessionManager;
                }
            }
            class NestedSessionManager
            {
                internal static readonly SessionFactoryProvider sessionManager =
                    new SessionFactoryProvider();
            }
   }
```

Also in my app I bind SessionFactoryProvider to ISessionFactoryProvider via ninject 
`kernel.Bind<ISessionFactoryProvider>().To<SessionFactoryProvider>().InSingletonScope();`

So my question why do i get this error?

Comment: Don't be mislead by the `ThreadSafeDictionary` in the stack trace.  I don't think that this is a threading issue.  This is more likely a problem with your NHibernate mappings.  Do you have two entities that have the same class name?  Perhaps in different namespaces?

Comment: @DanielSchilling if it was to be duplicate mapping, wouldn't the error always appear, not "sometimes" ?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no answer... But you seem to be mixing a slightly different version of this http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx#nested-cctor with inheritance. I don't see any flaw here (but I'm not a C# ninja). You also mix it with your IOC singleton implementation. I guess the issue might be here, and you should only rely on your IOC for singleton implementation.

Comment: @jbl, thank u for the answer. My mappings are ok. Yes I mix singletone technique with inheritance. Is it possible. Also I point ninject to serve ISessionFactoryProvider in singletone scope. I try remove singetone scope

Answer (score 0):

In my comments, I said I saw no flaw in your Singleton implementation.
In fact, there is an obvious one : your `SessionFactoryProvider` parameterless constructor is not private, because `SessionFactoryProvider` does not have any overload for its constructor.

So the compiler generates a public parameterless constructor for `SessionFactoryProvider` 
see [Should we always include a default constructor in the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3692042/1236044)

So any code can instantiate a new `SessionFactoryProvider` through 
this public constructor (this should be easy to test) which is used by Ninject to instantiate the class. (This was the point that puzzled me : how does Ninject instantiate the class ? It should not be able to instantiate a class without public constructor).
I guess this is how you end-up with duplicate `SessionFactoryProvider`.

You should implement your `SessionFactoryProvider` with a public constructor, leaving out any consideration of singleton implementation. Then just rely on Ninject and its `InSingletonScope()` to provide singleton functionnality