# Does a window's default constructor have to be public?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a dialog window for my WPF application.  I know that WPF requires that all controls have a default constructor and I can create all the constructors that take all the parameters that I want.  But does the default constructor have to be public?  Can I make it internal, or private, or even protected?

Comment: without being public, you (or whatever auto-mechanism) cannot create an instance of the class ***outside*** the class, maybe using Reflection can do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should we always include a default constructor in the class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692042/should-we-always-include-a-default-constructor-in-the-class) Not an exact duplicate but answerer contains what the OP wants

Comment: That depends on the requirement. If you don't want access to default constructor from outside the class then make it private, If you don't want access outside of assembly then make it internal.

Comment: If you don't have a default constructor or if it is not public, you can't instantiate it from `Xaml`. If that's ok for you then go ahead..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Controls dont need a default constructor in WPF, unless you want to instantiate the control from XAML.

It's perfectly legal to have a control like this:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
      public MyUserControl(string someParameter) : this()
      { 
         InitializeComponent();
      }
}
```

As shown, the default constructor was removed, you need to make sure that `InitializeComponent();` is called, though.

If you instantiate the control from XAML, then the default constructor must be visible by the embedding control

Therefore it can be `internal` if the embedding control is in the same assembly, or it has to be `public` otherwise.

Comment: It's a dialog.  It won't be instantiated in XAML in this application.

Comment: @TonyVitabile then your constructor simply needs to be visible to the calling code.

Comment: Granted.  There are multiple constructors. There is a default constructor that calls `InitializeComponent` because VS built it by default.  There's another that takes arguments.  The first thing it does is call the default constructor.  I just don't want code outside of the class calling that default constructor.  Actually, I may be able to remove the default constructor entirely.

Comment: yes you need to call `InitializeComponent()`. Make the default constructor private and call it from your non default constructors. I think I misunderstood where your question was aimed at.

Comment: Yep, I know I have to call `IntializeComponent`.  If I removed the default constructor, I'd move the call to `InitializeComponent` into the public constructor.  It's working fine with the default constructor set to private.  I had thought the designer in VS would have a fit if the default constructor didn't exist or wasn't public.

Comment: When I make my `MainWindow` constructor `internal` I get this error: *System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''No matching constructor found on type MainWindow. You can use the Arguments or FactoryMethod directives to construct this type.* Even the `MainWindow` class itself is `internal`, and that actually works fine after adding `x:ClassModifier="internal"` to the XAML. This makes it even weirder to why I can't get the constructor working as `internal`.

Answer (score 1):

making your constructor internal ensures the type will only ever be instantiated by types within the current assembly, even if it is later decided that the type itself should be public instead of internal. In other words you could decide to change the type's visibility without lifting restrictions on its instantiation.

Making the constructor public has the opposite effect (obviously), and might be sensible if you want for it to be possible to instantiate the type anywhere it is visible.