# Adding common classes used for DI in a single class, is this Ok?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

With DI injection things can get a bit repetitive. for example the Base Controllers depend on 5 different constructor injections. So every time you create a controller all those things need injecting into the controller and base controller. What if I contain all the things used for DI into a separate class like this..

```
public class BaseApiDIContainer(
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
    ISettingsFactory settingsFactory,
    IEmailService emailService,
    MembershipDbContext db,
    IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor
    )
{
    protected internal UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager => userManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof( userManager));
    protected internal ISettingsFactory SettingsFactory => settingsFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(settingsFactory));
    protected internal IEmailService EmailService => emailService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userManager));
    protected internal MembershipDbContext Db => db ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(MembershipDbContext));
    protected internal IHttpContextAccessor ContextAccessor => contextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(contextAccessor));
}
Collapse
```

Then we can just call those in the controllers. example..

```
public  class ApBaseApiController : ApiController
{

    protected UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private ISettingsFactory _settingsFactory;
    private IEmailService _emailService;
    private IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
    protected MembershipDbContext;

public ApBaseApiController(BaseApiDIContainer container) : base(container)
    _userManager = container.UserManager;
    _settingsFactory = container.SettingsFactory;
    _emailService = container.EmailService;
    _contextAccessor = container.ContextAccessor;
}
}

public AccountController(BaseApiDIContainer container) : ApBaseApiController(container)
{
  public ApplicationUser DoSomethingWithUser()
  {
    return _userManager.FindUserAsync(currentUser); //protected property
  }
}
```

And obviously register them to the DI container, the only issue I can see is everything in the class much have the same service lifetime.

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<BaseApiDIContainer>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<BaseDIContainer>();
```

With my limited programming knowledge, I just wanted to know if this would be a good solution to cut down on repetitive code.

I just wanted to know if this would be a good solution to cut down on repetitive code.

Comment: Maybe - if you feel a class has too many injected dependencies it's probably doing too much and needs to be split into different classes. Or that some of the dependencies aren't needed. Do *all* controllers in your application need access to UserManager? Do all of them send email? I doubt it, which means those services shouldn't be injected in the base controller

Comment: Also: repetition is not automatically and inherently bad in all forms and cases.

Comment: JFYI you don't need `IHttpContextAccessor` in controllers, they already have access to context.

Comment: If you have a dependency that's only being used by one method in the controller, consider injecting it as a method parameter using `[FromServices]` so that it's not created for *every* request that's handled by that controller.

Comment: @GuruStron, is that also the case in API Controllers?

Comment: @Nick1991 yes, it is.

Comment: This is a good as well as a bad solution IMHO. Basically it violates the SOLID principles, reinforcing the comment made by @PanagiotisKanavos. Your BaseAPI controller is just ending up doing too many things. This would work in small scale applications brilliantly and cut down on development time, but as you scale up it would become messy and tough to manage

Comment: Related questions: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41450993/applying-dependency-injection-when-base-class-constructor-contains-arguments), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295804/simple-injector-inject-multiple-dependency-in-baseclass), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779738/implicitly-injecting-dependency-in-base-class-while-derived-class-is-resolved-th).

Comment: @GuruStron Thanks, In my API Controllers I was inheriting from APIController instead of Controller.

Comment: @Nick1991 what is `ApiController`?