# What is the difference between the parameterless constructor with no members VS default constructor compiler creates in c#?

Tags: c#, constructor

```
class Constructor
{
    Constructor()
    {
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Constructor obj = new Constructor();
    }
}

class Compiler
{
    Compiler obj1 = new Compiler();
}
```

In the first program I created a constructor with no members and in the second program I'm not created any constructor so the compiler creates a default constructor so what's the difference between them in c#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should we always include a default constructor in the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692042/should-we-always-include-a-default-constructor-in-the-class)

Answer (score 0):

Reference: [Microsoft docs - Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors)

"...classes without constructors are given a public parameterless constructor by the C# compiler in order to enable class instantiation."

Cases when you do need to write a parameterless constructor:

1. When you have other constructors defined in the class.
2. When you want to use a different protection level for your parameterless constructor.

Comment: why do compiler give public constructor

Comment: @Viknesh The main point of creating a non-static class is that you want to create objects of it, thus the compiler generate the default constructor as public.

Comment: But the default access modifier for the constructor is Public

Answer (score 0):

There are *other problems* (see below) in the code shown, but in general there is no difference between an empty parameterless constructor you create vs. an empty parameterless constructor the compiler creates. It's possible they result in slightly different compiled code, but for all intents and purposes they do the same thing.

---

*Other problems in the code shown...*

This will result in an infinite recursion any time you try to create an instance of it:

```
class Compiler
{
    Compiler obj1 = new Compiler();
}
```

And this constructor is *not* the same as the compiler-default one because [class members are `private` by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers):

```
class Constructor
{
    Constructor()
    {
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Constructor obj = new Constructor();
    }
}
```